# Dynamic Modal routing with NextJS like Instagram

Tags: reactjs, next.js, modal-dialog, url-routing

I am looking for someone to help me with the following issue:

I am trying to implement a modal system where the modals are dependent on the route using NextJS.

So say I am on the following page:

```
website.com/help
```

and say I have the modals category1, category2, and category3, all of which I would prefer to be able to persist after closing them (they are loading iframes), however this is not a must.

Then I would want the routes for these modals to be:

```
website.com/help/category1
website.com/help/category2
website.com/help/category3
```

I have already found this in the official NextJS examples:
[with-route-as-modal](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-route-as-modal)

But the problem I am having  is that with queryString routing, when you reload/visit the modal route directly, the modal wont be used. So the content will become full screen (it is a page of its own).

With dynamic routing, this is not an issue, since if you visit the modal route directly the modal will be kept. But the problem I am having with this is that these modals aren't exactly modals, the original page "behind" the modal just becomes the body background. The other issue is that I wont be able to persist these.

Here is the demo on stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/github/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-route-as-modal?file=README.md

I would appreciate anyone helping me with this so much because it has really driven me mad trying to solve this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a solution that you may like. For the example you provided you only need to import `<Grid/>` in `/article/[articleId].js` like it's done in `/index.js`

so when you open the modal the articles/posts list is shown in the background

```js
// article/[articleId].js
import Grid from '../../components/Grid';

<>
   <Modal
        isOpen={true}
        onRequestClose={() => router.push('/', undefined, { scroll: false })}
        contentLabel="Post modal"
   >
        <Article id={articleId} pathname={router.pathname} />
   </Modal>
   <Grid />
</>
```

don't forget to give `scroll` false in `router.push()` and `<Link/>` so when you go back to articles/posts list it doesn't jump to the top of the page

```
router.push('/', undefined, { scroll: false })

<Link 
      key={index}
      href="/article/[articleId]"
      as={`/article/${id}`}
      scroll={false} 
>
      <a className={styles.postCard}>{id}</a>
</Link>
```

you can see an example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-rkrovd

Comment: Thank you so much!! That indeed did the job! 

It was a whole lot more than just the Grid on the page, so I simply copied the whole page haha. Maybe not the prettiest solution but a solution nonetheless, and believe me when I say that I have looked and looked for solutions.

Edit: and using shallow routing, you don't even notice that it's two different pages!

Answer (score 0):

in App router version of next you could use [Intercepting Routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/intercepting-routes)
this next docs introduce [NextGram](https://github.com/vercel-labs/nextgram/blob/main/Readme.md) as an example, check [demo](https://nextgram.vercel.app/).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).